# How to start text in the left top corner in TextFormField

Tags: flutter, dart

I have TextFormField and I increased height of this field. I would like to start text from the left top corner and make that text will break at the end of the line. So if someone will put a lot of text, field will have X lines not only one.

How it looks now:

[image]

How it should looks like

[image]

Code:

```
 TextFormField(
                      controller: contentController,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        contentPadding: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            vertical: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .10,
                            horizontal: 10.0),
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        hintText: 'Treść',
                        fillColor: Color(0xffffffff),
                        filled: true,
                        prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.topic_rounded),
                      ),
                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                          return ErrorMessages.NO_CONTENT_MESSAGE;
                        }
                      },
                    ),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things you can do:

1. You can add `maxLines: desiredNumberOfLines` and `textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.top,` to your `TextFormField` and wrap your prefix icon with `Padding` like this:

```
TextFormField(
  textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.top,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    prefixIcon: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 70.0),
      child: Icon(
        Icons.topic_rounded,
      ),
    ),
   ...
  ),
  maxLines: 5,
 ...
),
```

2. You can wrap your `TextFormField` with a `SizedBox` widget and add `expands: true` to the text field, also you have to set `minLines` and `minLines` to `null`, because otherwise you get an error. The icon alignment can be the same as in the previous example with wrapping the icon with a `Padding` widget or you can do it the other way, which is shown in this example. It is done by using a prefix parameter instead of prefixIcon like this:

```
SizedBox(
  height: 200,
  child: TextFormField(
    textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.top,
    expands: true,
    maxLines: null,
    minLines: null,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      prefix: Icon(
        Icons.topic_rounded,
      ),
      ...
    ),
   ...
  ),
)
```

Choose a combination of text and icon alignment methods that works best for you.

Comment: This is how the first example looks for me: [link](https://i.imgur.com/QSArW54.png). 
You might have to adjust the values to get your desired result. Could you provide more information on what doesn't work for you there?

Comment: Also, there might be some difference in the look between my `TextFormField` and the one you provided in a picture because I removed some of your styling code that is not related to the issue.

Comment: Nevermind, trial and error method I achieved what I wanted, but `  textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.top,` is not needed. It does not change anything.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the height of your `prefix` icon by default it will be in the center. But to make it go on top you need to add `Container()` in which you will add your icon like this.

```
          TextFormField(
              minLines: 4,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
              maxLines: 4,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                hintText: 'Treść',
                fillColor: Color(0xffffffff),
                filled: true,
                prefixIcon: Container(
                  width: 20,
                  height: 100,
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Icon(Icons.topic_rounded),
                      ),
                      Container(),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                prefixIconConstraints: BoxConstraints(
                  minWidth: 35,
                  minHeight: 0,
                ),
              ),
              validator: (value) {
                if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                  return "error";
                }
                return null;
              },
            )
```

It will look like this

[image]

Comment: If I made for example height: 150 then text go down. How can I make it to be like on the screen (the icon is on the left and text on the right in the same line)?  I have removed exmpty container and still it works like on the screen, so it seems it is not necessary.

Comment: It seems like prefixIconConstrainets is also not necessary.